# Twilio conversations "messageAdded" event sometimes does not fire after message is sent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, twilio, twilio-conversations

### Description:

After `onMessageSent` handler is registered on Twilio `Conversation` object, when new message is sent using `conversation.sendMessage(messageText)` sometimes handler is not called. This seems to happen randomly e.g:
I'm sending 4 messages `A,B,C,D` in succession.
Handler is called for messages `A,B and D`, but not for `C`.

Also sometimes it seems to get stuck totally, so only refresh would help.

After reloading all sent messages appear in conversation

### What I have ruled out:

- multiple Client references
- mutliple Conversation references
- handler removed in `useEffect` cleanup function
- handler not attached to Conversation object (it's there under `Conversation._events.messageAdded`)

### Code:

```
import React from "react";
import { Conversation, Message, Paginator } from "@twilio/conversations";
import { useTwilioClient } from "./Twilio.context";

const messagesPageSize = 50;

export const useTwilioConversation = (sid: string) => {
  const twilioClient = useTwilioClient();

  const [twilioConversation, setTwilioConversation] =
    React.useState<Conversation | null>(null);
  const [messages, setMessages] = React.useState<Message[]>([]);
  const [paginator, setPaginator] = React.useState<Paginator<Message>>();
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState(false);

  const fetchMore = React.useCallback(() => {
    if (!twilioConversation || !paginator) {
      return;
    }

    paginator.prevPage().then((paginator) => {
      setPaginator(paginator);
      setMessages((prev) => paginator.items.concat(prev));
    });
  }, [paginator, twilioConversation]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (!twilioClient) {
      return;
    }

    setIsLoading(true);

    const getTwilioConversation = async () => {
      const conversation = await twilioClient.getConversationBySid(sid);
      await conversation.setAllMessagesRead();
      setTwilioConversation(conversation);

      const paginator = await conversation.getMessages(messagesPageSize);
      setPaginator(paginator);
      setMessages(paginator.items);
    };

    getTwilioConversation().finally(() => {
      setIsLoading(false);
    });
  }, [twilioClient, sid]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (!twilioConversation) {
      return;
    }

    const handleMessageAdded = (message: Message) => {
      setMessages((prev) => [...prev, message]);
    };
    twilioConversation.on("messageAdded", handleMessageAdded);

    return () => {
      twilioConversation?.removeListener("messageAdded", handleMessageAdded);
    };
  }, [twilioConversation]);

  return {
    messages,
    twilioConversation,
    fetchMore,
    hasMore: !!paginator?.hasPrevPage,
    isLoading,
    setMessages,
  };
};
```

### SDK version: 2.2.0

Comment: Did you solved it?

Comment: [ditao](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2494218/ditao) nope.